# selinux multiple types for directory

Tags: fedora, selinux

For a new department I created a new mount point /dept/dev and in here are currently 2 dirs: samba and svn, so we have:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 /dept/dev/samba/*
unconfined_u:object_r:svnserve_content_t:s0 /dept/dev/svn/*
```

(/dept and /dept/dev are also "samba_share_t" as that one was created first)

samba works fine, svn does not:

```
AVC avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=7126 comm="svnserve" name="/" dev="sdb1" ino=512 scontext=system_u:system_r:svnserve_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

(I think 'name' in the above is the directory it's trying to search?)

It seems that because the higher up directory is samba_share_t, that a directory below that can't be svnserve_content_t ? If this is correct how can I accomplish this? Do I need to make /dept and /dept/dev public_t ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to tell SELinux to that `/dept/svn/*` needs to be `svnserve_content_t`. You can do that by adding a suitable regex ...

This

```
semanage fcontext -a -t svnserve_content_t "/dept/svn(/.*)?"
restorecon -rv /dept/svn
```

should do what you want.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Do you know why the chcon didn't work? The directories looked the same when I used ls -Z to check.